# Overpaying your bill

Tags: finance

(Please tell me exactly how you found the answer and what you did because I'm a Year 7 and this is a Year 9 question.)

Mr. Rich decides to pay a bill using internet banking. The bill is a two-digit whole number $ab$. He accidentally inserts an extra digit after the b. Later he finds out he overpaid his bill by $647. What was his original bill?

I started working it out like this

$(100a+10b+c)-(10a+b)=9(10a+b)+c$

But then I got stuck.  What I don't understand is how you're meant to proceed. Are you meant to do anything with the $c$? Plus, are the digits different by placing two different pro numerals or are they the same? Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should include your own work in your question.

Comment: Between this and your other questions, it really looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.  Try the problem yourself first, and show us some of your efforts.  Indicate where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I'm just trying Year 9 and 10 questions for extension. This isn't homework

Comment: We cannot know if you are or not and appearence is all we can go by so if you make it look like it, we will assume you are. It is often better to state purpose, show a genuine attempt and the more you can say what you know and hwat you do NOT understand, the more legitimate it'll appear to be and we will adapt our response accordingly.

Comment: What is 7 year?

Comment: @ marshal craft It says year 7

Comment: That it an invalid answer to the question I asked. You knew what I was referring and can bother to correct me, however wont explain what I had asked?

Comment: @Zelos Malum It's hard to follow your periphrases.

Comment: Guys don't bother I've worked out that Mr. Rich paid $718 and he should have paid 71

Comment: You found the overpayment is $9(10a+b)+c$. When you divide it by $9$ you'll get a remainder of $c$. But you know the overpayment is $647$. Can you obtain $c$ from this? (EDIT: I can see I'm late, too long betwen starting a comment and actually posting it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already on the right way:

Actual bill: $10a+b$.

Actually Paid: $100a + 10b+c$

Overpaid: $647=(100a+10b+c)-(10a+b)=90a+9b+c=647$

With the last equation and with the knowledge that $a,b,c\in\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ (i.e. they can be only integers from 0 to 9) you can solve this.

Hint: Try e.g. $a=2$ and see that in this case either $b$ or $c$ need to be greater than 9.

Answer (score 0):

$(100a+10b+c)-(10a+b)=647$.

$90a+9b+c=647$.

There are three unknowns and one equation. We also require integer solutions from the field $\Bbb Z_{10}$.

Comment: Don't worry  I just experimented with substituting a,b and c until I found the answer.

Comment: Ok thank you and if you could explain what year 7 is. College is it?

Comment: @marshall craft yes

Comment: So post doc homework this is?

Comment: The integer solutions don't come from the field $\Bbb Z_{10}$, partly because $\Bbb Z_{10}$ is not a field, and mostly because these are integers, not elements of a ring with nonzero characteristic. You simply mean that the solutions are elements of the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.